# What innovation made WiFi amenable to mobile devices without prematurely depleting them of power?

Tags: power, wifi

In June 2004, the Economist, in reference to the nascent WiFi standard stated that "*It is currently too power-hungry for mobile devices"*

So how did WiFi go from being extremely power-hungry to being suitable to mobile device usage?

Comment: the economist is not quite an electrical engineering specialist magazine, is it?

Comment: Well, as a general readership magazine, it covers areas like electronics, biotech and cryptocurrency in a very impressive way. I find its articles pragmatic, insightful but without being too geeky.

Comment: yeah, but they're sometimes plain wrong.

Comment: Name a publication that doesn't get it wrong from time to time!

Comment: How did house-brick-sized mobile phones (that almost needed to be towed around on trolleys) become so small that inmates at prisons can (somehow) conceal them about their person (even in a shower). I do know how but I'm too polite to say. It's called progress. Voting to close this not-applicable question off.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the answer is simply "progress" and to define that progress (in EE terms) to someone who didn't know that, is basically starting at the beginning of science levels in primary schools and therefore is too-broad to consider here.

Comment: Dear Andy, I think by saying it was "progress" is sounds a bit crude if not ignorant. I am trying to find out what technical breakthrough made the 802.11 wireless standard went from being extremely power hungry to a standard which today can be used for several hours on mobile devices. Obviously battery-life has improved but I am trying to find out what iteration to 802.11 made it more power efficient. I suggest you take your unhelpful broad brushstroke and uninquisitive commentary elsewhere. Thank you.

Comment: @daikin no breaktrhough. There's very rarely "breakthroughs" (that's more of a marketing term). There's always development. Also, don't act as if 802.11 isn't defined by people who earn their money through implementing that standard in devices later on. You got everything backwards.

Comment: @daikin I'm very partial to saying that Andy is 100% right: this is really too broad if this is actually your stance. My answer was written in the assumption that you know how the standardization process roughly looks, and how far off the Economist was.

Comment: @daikin. Sorry by the treatment given to you here. Your question is totally pertinent and legitimate. It just wasn't read by a real expert in Wi-fi hardware. Another option is to look for a forum dedicated to digital communications. Good luck.

Comment: @DirceuRodriguesJr I think you would be more than welcome to write an answer!

Comment: With mobiles using more and more compute power, and batteries and user expectations changing to accommodate that, the consumption of the WiFi service, assisted by continuous small improvements in its technology, has become less of an issue.

Comment: WiFi didn't change that much, but batteries grew from 1000 to 5000 mAh since then.

Answer (score 22):

> In June 2004, the Economist,

A financial / economy magazine should be read with a lot of caution when it comes to technical claims made therein – the people writing, interviewing, editing such a magazine aren't engineers!

Just the same applies the other way around: I wouldn't trust IEEE Spectrum to be the best source for discussion of economy.

> in reference to the nascent WiFi standard

"Nascent" as in "standardized five years before". If you consider the speed of mobile phone development that we already saw in the 2000s, that isn't "nascent". That's "mature, if not a little old already".

> stated that "It is currently too power-hungry for mobile devices"

Well, either the Economist was simply wrong, or something fundamental happened between that article and the release of things like third-gen E-series Nokia phones a year later.

Of course, there was ongoing development in the area of batteries, making higher-power devices feasible. At the same time, power efficiency of silicon of course continuously increased.

But let's be honest here: the Economist was wrong.

Wifi integration was not yet market ready in 2004 for mobile mass products, but power demand was just one of many things, and I'd say that in 2004, companies actually designing phone SoCs would already have had feasibility studies done that showed it was very realistic to have a Wifi phone out a year or two later. Development of such things don't happen in a couple of months. It takes planning and *severe* investments.

> So how did WiFi go from being extremely power-hungry to being suitable to mobile device usage?

It was never "extremely power-hungry": That's not a true claim. As it was standardized, it was meant to later be implemented in mobile devices. That was among the many goals standardization committees have. So, the whole standard was written by people who had a good idea that it has to be possible to implement it efficiently enough to put it in a mobile device later on.

Andy put it very well: the reason for it then becoming actually feasible is called *progress*.

The same as for every other technology:

- increase in battery capacity
- improvement in semiconductor static and dynamic power losses
- improvement in the efficiency of power supplies
- improvement of algorithms

in particular for Wifi:

- lower-power oscillators
- better ADCs
- smarter synchronization algorithms being available
- higher-efficiency implementation of "old" forward error correction methods.

**Oh**, by the way: just found out that Nokia made the Wifi-connected [Nokia 9500 Communicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_9500_Communicator), and put it to market 6 months after the Economist claimed it was too power-hungry. Sure, that was slow Wifi (802.11b, 11 Mb/s max) by modern standards, but a year after that they brought out the 802.11g (54 Mb/s) 9300i, and another year later, the whole E61, E7x series, and Wifi became a standard feature for smart phones at that point.

Comment: Thanks Marcus, that's very informative.                                                                                      "I'd say that in 2004, companies actually designing phone SoCs would already have had feasibility studies done that showed it was very realistic to have a wifi phone out a year or two later" And a very valid comment.

Comment: BTW Marcus, was there ever a case where a standardisation committee such as the IEEE introduced a standard which was later considered flawed?

Comment: @daikin Many. One example is the 802.11 Wired Equivalent Privacy security algorithm

Comment: One interesting example of the thinking that went into 802.11 with power in mind was that nodes are permitted to set rather long beacon times.  The result is a very high latency for the first message sent to them, but in return they don't have to have the transmitters or recivers energized.

Comment: Just because Nokia put WiFi into a phone doesn't mean it wasn't too power-hungry. I had a Nokia N900 for a long time and I almost exclusively used 3G even when WiFi was available, precisely because the latter was just too power-hungry.

Comment: @AndreKR hm, fair point, but then again, that was definetely an early phone, and I remember generally the same as you: you keep wifi off, unless you really want to e.g. download an attachment that would be expensive to download via 3G. I think our expectations of "always connected battery life" have significantly shifted in the last ~1.4 decades.

Comment: After I switched to Android (Galaxy Note 2) it took quite a while until I was convinced that on that device WiFi/3G doesn't really matter regarding power consumption - but it eventually happened. So there is definitely a difference between the N900's and the Note 2's WiFi chipset.

Comment: @AndreKR yeah, took ~3 years to improve that, and also, that was definitely the period when Nokia lost leadership in the phone market and Samsung rose, so it might simply be the case that the technology Nokia had was at its fullest potential and couldn't be improved, whereas Samsung started with a big budget to develop from scratch.

Answer (score 10):

Questions which call for speculation as to what someone meant are always deeply problematic.  That said, there is a notable generation change in 2.4 GHz WiFi which fits your timeframe.

802.11b is a standard from 1999

802.11g is a standard from 2003

This may be significant, as 802.11g uses a higher throughput modulation scheme.  As Texas Instruments [argues in a contemporaneous white paper](https://www.ti.com/pdfs/bcg/80211_wp_lowpower.pdf) a higher data rate means running the radio for shorter periods of time to accomplish the same task, and thus even if actually running the radio may cost slightly more power, getting the job done ends up costing less.

But as that paper points out, power is not only about modulation scheme.  It is also about the sophistication of approach to the engineering problem overall.  Examples they give include being able to rapidly move between operating and standby modes, and having intelligent processing of beacons (which likely means accurately predicting when you will next hear from the base station, and turning on your receiver just then).  In general, these would be examples of a maturing technology - WiFi chip manufacturers with four or five more years experience making WiFi gear are going to have come up with ways to make more power efficient WiFi gear.

Granted, while the engineering behind the TI paper linked above is presumably sound, we should also keep in mind that a paper like that is published as part of an effort to sell chips - to sell TI's new WiFi chips, rather than someone else's, rather than their older ones, and rather than not having that functionality in a product.  So it's both an illustration of useful ideas for how to achieve WiFi connectivity at low power, and an argument of opinion that the result is useful.

(Would 2003 models still be expected to support the 802.11b?  In general, yes, that functionality has been retained.  But what makes a product viable is that there's a viable way of using it, especially when the newer 802.11g that would be gaining base station market share as the products that could benefit from it were being released.  And smartphone users haven't always kept WiFi enabled when they weren't actually using it, anyway)

Comment: This answer would be better if it cited some sources about whether the first WiFi enabled phones actually supported that newer standard and if their manuals said stuff like that users might want to upgrade their base stations if they want acceptable battery life.

Comment: @Nobody wikipedia: [E61](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_E61): 54 Mb/s. so yes, 802.11g.

Answer (score 9):

I think the power efficiency trend of WiFi has more to do with the underlying CMOS technology and libraries than with choice of signal processing algorithms.

Not only has the CMOS transistor feature been reduced into nanometer technology since then, but also newer low leakage devices are added to analog and digital circuits. As for digital circuits, new libraries with lower power latch/registers, and clock trees were introduced, and we saw the beginnings of power/voltage islands. While these techniques were known much earlier, it took until mid 2000s to appear in commercial ASIC synthesis tools.

Clearly, all these factors play a role in all/most circuits in a mobile device, including the cellular technology and the processors.

Specifically for WiFi, 802.11n introduced scheduling, which was later improved in 802.11ac. This allowed WiFi devices to enter a sleep state rather than continually sniff the ether for beacons and possible packets addressed to it.

One could argue that some of the improved WiFi performance is obtained by MORE power hungry processing algorithms (2x2 ... 4x2 MIMO comes to mind for mobile devices), and that the new circuit technologies were require to offset the power consumption, and possibly reduce it further.

This is a simple question asking to enumerate and weigh multi-factorial effects across different disciplines (analog, RF, digital, S/W, signal processing), and so it will yield a complex and probably at all times incomplete answer.

Here are a few graphs to highlight the effects of electronics and transistors to illustrate these underlying trends.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First, WiFi is still more power-hungry than the cell data connection in a good cell coverage. (It can be pretty much the other way round in a weak coverage and one can save a great deal of battery power using VoWiFi (if available) instead of the usual cell voice and data service)

I am almost sure WiFi still has no standardized means of transmitter power management and it either always transmits full-power (~100mW) or uses some non-standard tricks in order to save power. Cellular handheld unit, OTOH, can transmit up to 1W or 2W when needed, but all the cell protocols from 2G and later (not sure about NMT) include a standard method of making the phone to speak up (or down). It is important not only because of the battery drain, but also to make less noise for other nearby cells.

Speaking of data rates, modulation methods, etc..., there is a lot of convergence between cell and wifi technologies, meaning that cell brings better data rates and becomes more computationally intensive, lagging less and less from WiFi. (ex. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/5G#Convergence_of_Wi-Fi_and_cellular)). It is the silicon improvements that make the power requirements of these technologies acceptable, but the convergence means there is already not much of a difference between the cell and WiFi in regard to electrical power (spare for the transmitter).

Comment: Your answer is based on the assumption that wifi consumes more battery than cell data, which is [false](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.technipages.com/does-wi-fi-consume-more-battery-power-than-3g-or-4glte/amp) .

Comment: Either of them may consume more or less, depending on the signal level, usage profile (send/receive) and other factors. Where I live, cell service is almost stable, but is a battery drain. Where I work (or used to, before the covid crisis forced me to work from my bedroom), cell uses less battery than the wifi (but the cell tower is some 40m from the office).